# Latest String value assigned to a variable is not returned by the function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the Below code i am trying to get the user input until it matches the value in the 'type_details' dictionaries.
But the function is returning the invalid input but not the correct value entered finally

```
Enter the preferred Type:fsafs 
Please Choose the Type available in the Menu 
Enter the preferred Type:Cup
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Workspace-Python\MyFirstPythonProject\Main.py", line 186, in <module>
typeprice = type_details[typeValue] 
KeyError: 'fsafs'
```

Below is the code

```
type_details = {'Plain':1.5,
             'Waffle':2,
             'Cup':1}
def getType():     
    type = input("Enter the preferred Type:")
    if not ValidateString(type):
        print("Type is not valid")
        getType()
    else:
        check = None
        for ct in type_details:
            if ct.lower() == type.lower():
                check = True
                type=ct
                break
            else:
                check = False
        if not check:
            print("Please Choose the Type available in the Menu")
            getType()
    return type

typeValue = getType()
typeprice = type_details[typeValue]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple as this?

Get user input, check if it's in dictionary, return if so else continue in the infinite loop.

```
type_details = {'Plain':1.5,
             'Waffle':2,
             'Cup':1}

def getType():             
    while True:
        user_in = input("Enter the preferred Type: ")
        if user_in in type_details:
            return user_in

user_in = getType()                       
print(f'You entered: {user_in}')
print(f'Type Price: {type_details[user_in]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time `getType()` is called (even inside itself) a new local variable `type` is created whose content is lost if it isn't returned to the calling function.

The content of `type` in the calling `getType()` isn't modified.